# prevent openpyxl from doing a date field conversion

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, datetime-format

I use openpyxl with python. I have columns with long date type example 01 January 2000 . when importing the excel file openpyxl does an automatic conversion from date to short example 2000-01-01 00:00:00. I do not see this conversion I need to use the long date of the excel file leaving the information of the excel file in general format

```py
wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0].values
header = next(ws) #get the header row

my_data = []
for row in ws:                     
    my_data.append(dict(zip(header, row)))
    print(row)
```

output:

('300.0001.19', 'NGALULA MBUYAMBA BIBICHE', 'la troisième année de graduat', 'téchniques médicales', 'sage-femme ', None, None, 'Mikalayi', **datetime.datetime(1980, 12, 10, 0, 0)**, 'donnant accès aux études supérieures et universitaires', 'de première et deuxième années de graduat en téchniques médicales', 'satisfaction', **datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 28, 0, 0)**, **datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 17, 0, 0)**, **datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 31, 0, 0)**, 6913, 'CXC', 'B', **datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 17, 0, 0)**, 'GRADUE')
('300.0002.19', 'DIPA MPONGO GRACIA', 'la troisième année de graduat', 'téchniques médicales', 'sage-femme ', None, None, 'Kananga', datetime.datetime(1996, 10, 5, 0, 0), 'donnant accès aux études supérieures et universitaires', 'de première et deuxième années de graduat en téchniques médicales', 'satisfaction', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 31, 0, 0), 6914, 'CXC', 'B', datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 17, 0, 0), 'GRADUE')

Comment: The cells have been formatted as dates. You can choose how you want them to appear yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When Openpyxl reads a cell value it will translate the type to a Python type.
For dates this would usually be a Python datetime value.

**Note** what you see in Excel is just the display format used by excel on the underlying value of the cell
for example the cell shows  '01 January 2000' where the format '[$-C09]dd mmmm yyyy;@' is applied to the cell.

Therefore the value '01 January 2000' as a 'Date' in Excel will be read by Openpyxl as Python Datetime '2000-01-01 00:00:00'. 
However if instead '01 January 2000' was a String in the cell, (Excel would be using a display format of General or Text) Openpyxl would read it as a string and it remains as '01 January 2000'.

Therefore you could save dates as a string in Excel and there would be no need to convert when read by Openpyxl if that works for you.
Otherwise you can convert the value to a string after it's read from Excel for display purposes.

For example where the cell

```
...
### Cell A1 contains a 'Date' displayed as '01 January 2000' by Excel date format
dtval = ws['A1'].value  # This value is type datetime 
print(dtval)  # This prints '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
strval = dtval.strftime("%d %B %Y")  # This converts datetime value to a string in the date format "%d %B %Y" 
print(strval)  # This prints string '01 January 2000'
```

Obviously the string Date values being strings cannot directly be used for any date calculations in Python.